# How to disable systemd service in rescue mode

Tags: debian, systemd

I have a service that kills the system every time it boots (OOM). I need to get rid of it, but debian 8 doesn't seem to have recovery boot option anymore, so I had to boot using cd and used rescue, that chrooted to root FS.

Now when I do:

```
# systemctl
```

I get

```
Running in chroot, ignoring request.
```

So how can I disable it, when systemd doesn't allow me to change the configuration in rescue mode?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To disable it, you call `systemctl disable <service>`. Without arguments, `systemctl` displays the current state, which is obviously not possible in a chroot.

Alternatively, you can also go to `/etc/systemd/system/` and remove the symlink to your service (probably in the `multi-user.target.wants` folder).

If it is a service that is enabled by default, you need to create a symlink (named `<service>.service`) to `/dev/null` to disable it. Where the symlink needs to be depends on where in `/lib/systemd/system` the service is enabled.

Comment: Old good days of simple stupid init scripts... this is such a symlink hell.

Comment: With init scripts, it was also all symlinks. 

Comment: Good point :D hah